# Trying to install Ubuntu 19.10 with dual boot alongside windows 10 but there is no space available

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10, disk

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 19.10 on dual boot alongside windows 10 on my new Acer TC 885 UA92 Aspire. I burnt the installation disk and I can boot from it but when I start the installation process (after the keyboard setup and WiFi connection) I get a message that says that I need 8.6GB disk space but this computer has only 0.0GB.

I googled it this is what I already tried:

- I deactivated fast boot (from windows) AND safe boot (from BIOS).
- I shrank the space on the disk and made a 300GB "unallocated" partition (question: should I do anything else with that?) See the link below with a screenshot of what disk manager says.
- I tried Ubuntu without installing and it worked, but when I install from there I get the same error.

[image]

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and if SSD, updated that firmware? Fast Boot is a UEFI settting & should be off. Fast start up is a Windows setting & also needs to be off.  Are you booting in UEFI mode?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & Acer will need "trust" after install. http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: You should be able to install Ubuntu using "Something else" during installation. Click the plus sign at lower left and make an ext4 (Primary) root partition (/) in the unallocated space. There is already be an EFI partition from Windows. If you only have one drive put the bootloader on sda. only the / partition should have the format box checked.

Comment: I never got to see the "something else" option unfortunately... I am forced to quitting the installation before I get to that

Comment: I am wondering if I should format the Unallocated partition I made from Windows...

Comment: @Marco I've just run into the exact same problem on a brand new Win10 machine. Curious if you've made any progress...

Comment: Same issue with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS 64-bit desktop.

Comment: @NiloCK I couldn't find a way to do it. At the end I used a different SSD to install Ubuntu, and I kept Windows 10 on the SSD that came with the computer. It works well but the files that are on Windows cannot be seen by Ubuntu (and vice versa)

Comment: @Marco Thanks for the update. I'm on a laptop so a 2nd ssd isn't an option for me. I'll be sure to post here with any fix I come across.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your recovery partition on the PC is preventing Ubuntu from accessing that available space since its between 2 Windows partitions. I suggest to first image the drive if you can to an external HDD (I like Marcium on Windows), then nuke the recovery partition, and see if it installs. If you don't have a spare external drive, try to adjust the default installation target, may even be possible to create a small 1 GB partition in your 300 GB unallocated, using a clone tool like Macrium or dd in Linux to save the Recovery Partition over. That said Windows recovery is not something I would expect to work if partitions change, so still strongly suggest an image backup to an external drive.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I am not sure I can do that but I tried to install another SDD (from my old PC) and I can see the disk space on the new drive only. I guess that's an option although it is a bit annoying that all the space in the default SDD would go wasted. I don't really want to use windows but sometimes it's useful to have it. I still want to try and figure out what is preventing Ubuntu to see the partition(s) on the default drive

Answer (score 0):

Since you now have unallocated space, you can assign this to be the installation target for Ubuntu during the installation process.  From the installer's options, you want "Something else" (or whatever the current installer is calling this option).  Effectively, this allows you to manually partition the hard disk and, in particular, assign your unallocated space as an extended partition with part of this to root and another smaller part as swap space.  The basic process is as stated by C.S.Cameron in the comments, and is described in more detail, with screenshots, at: https://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/manual-partitioning-revisited/